# Python Inheritance With No Arguments

Tags: python, inheritance

So I'm getting my mind toyed with right now. I feel like I've found a bug in python, but I'm sure that can't be the case. Can someone point out what I'm missing?

```
class LinkedList():
    def __init__(self):
        pass


def SortedLinkedList(LinkedList):
    pass

new_list = SortedLinkedList()
```

gives

```
TypeError: SortedLinkedList() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
```

while

```
new_list = SortedLinkedList("wtf")
```

works fine. What is going on?

Comment: You wrote `def` instead of `class`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
def SortedLinkedList(LinkedList):
```

will create a function, not a class. Perhaps you meant

```
class SortedLinkedList(LinkedList):
```

Comment: Yeah, that would do it.

Comment: @aIKid He asked many questions but accepted answer to only one of them :(